# Possible to update an existing file when using file templates?

Tags: templates, resharper

I have a multi-file template that generates an interface and an implementation. I would like to update the IoC mappings in my solution, but this doesn't require a new file; it requires a snippet of code added to an existing file.

Is it possible to do a partial update of this kind?

So, for example, I'd reference the existing file, which contains the IoC mappings, and a code region to append some code to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, ReSharper's live templates don't work like this - they generate code rather than modify it. If the whole file is generated, delete it and regenerate it.

Comment: Would be handy if one could add code to an existing class. MVC's T4 controller templates do this. They append a DbSet for an entity to a specified database context somewhere in the solution.

Comment: Well, you could add a template that creates extension methods, or use partial classes. I don't think MVC T4's templates updates existing code - it's more likely that it re-generates everything.

Comment: It can hardly re-generate code that I've written. :)

Comment: Afraid not, I noticed it after doing, in Visual Studio 2013...  Add -> New Scaffolded Item... -> MVC5 Controller with Views, using Entity Framework.